# 'lines' function in R not showing

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I am trying to add lines for confidence intervals in R but lines() isn't working. In the following code b is a dataframe, 100 observations of 2 variables 'pred' and 'se'.

```
plot(c(1:300),b$pred,type="l",lwd=1.5)
lines(c(1:300),b$pred+2*b$se,type="l",lty=2,col='red')
```

The first line is working but the second is not. I have tried it with and without the x values (plot works with or without, lines works for neither). I can get lines to work for different dataframes, but not this one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can we have a [mcve]?  Guessing, the most obvious possibility is that the upper confidence limit you're trying to draw is outside out of the y-axis range of the plot (which is determined, by default, from the range of the y-variable in the original plot (`b$pred`).

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems very fragile to me to use `1:300` when also referencing `b`; it might work when `b` has 300 rows, but any other time it's going to either complain with warnings or recycling *silently* and show a misleading/meaningless plot. In general, "never" use hard-coded numbers when working programmatically like this, perhaps better `seq_len(nrow(b))` instead of `1:300`.
2. The bounds (x/y limits) for the plot are defined with the first `plot` command. After that, in base R graphics, no other plotting command will alter the limits. This means it is highly likely that all of `pred+2*se` are greater than `max(pred)`, so R thinks it's plotting the lines, but due to plotting inefficiency is really doing nothing since the lines are off-canvas.

   For this, you need to set the limits up front, perhaps:

   ```r
   xlims <- with(b, range(c(pred, pred+2*se), na.rm = TRUE))
   plot(seq_len(nrow(b)), b$pred, type="l", lwd=1.5, xlim=xlims)
   lines(seq_len(nrow(b)), b$pred+2*b$se, type="l", lty=2, col='red')
   ```

That should address your question. Continue reading if you want to consider migration to `ggplot2` ... not a one-for-one migration, not trivial, and perhaps premature at this point, but still something to think about.

3. While the above should fix the problem you cited, you might also consider migrating to `ggplot2`: it allows many other things (too many to discuss here), including the feature of updating the x/y limits with every "layer" you add to it. For instance, I wonder if the above will work:

   ```r
   library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(b, aes(x = seq_along(pred), y = pred)) +
     geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +            # this is doing what your first 'plot' is doing
     geom_line(aes(y = pred + 2*se), linewidth = 2, color = "red") # your call to lines
   ```

   (Notice no need to handle the x/y limits manually, ggplot2 figures it out for you with each layer added.)

   I'm going to infer that you'll want to add a `pred - 2*se` as well, in which case it'll be another call to `geom_line`, as in

   ```r
   ggplot(b, aes(x = seq_along(pred), y = pred)) +
     geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
     geom_line(aes(y = pred + 2*se), linewidth = 2, color = "red") +
     geom_line(aes(y = pred - 2*se), linewidth = 2, color = "blue")
   ```

   Note that `ggplot2` would actually prefer that you handle this with "long" data ... in that case, we can do something like below:

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
   b %>%
     select(x, pred, se) %>%
     mutate(
       x = row_number(),
       sehigh = pred + 2*se,
       selow  = pred - 2*se
     ) %>%
     pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "type", values_to = "val") %>%
     ggplot(aes(x, val, group = type, color = type)) +
     geom_line() +
     scale_color_manual(values = c(pred = "black", sehigh = "red", selow = "blue"))
   ```

   In this case, only one call to `geom_line`, and ggplot will handle colors automatically (based on the new categorical variable `type` that we created in a previous step).